# Get unread message via rest api for Rocket.chat

Tags: rocket.chat

I'm trying to get the numbers of direct unread messages in rocket.chat.

I'm on 0.53.0 and trying with /api/v1/im.history to get the numbers of unreads. If I set unreads to "true" I can't distinguish between read and unread.

What is the way to get the numbers of unread?

Answer (score 3):

When calling the [/api/v1/im.history](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/im/history) if you set unreads to true you should have 3 properties on the object returned:

- messages
- firstUnread
- unreadNotLoaded

This will be the first message unread.  You would need to then find all messages with a newer timestamp and that would be your unread messages.

Reference to the code generating this payload: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/0.53.0/packages/rocketchat-lib/server/methods/getChannelHistory.js#L72

Comment: This is wrong. the "unreads" are the messages not shown by the query. Not the unread messages.